# How to uninstall a package with illegal name with pip?

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation

I got a package with illegal name that I want to uninstall, and pip sees the name of the package as if I tried to use an uninstall "option".

I'm trying to remove all my packages to install them manually (I got a little mess there).
I uninstalled all the packages, but one.

When I'm running `pip list`, I get:

```
Package    Version
-jango     2.2.5
pip        19.2.3
setuptools 41.2.0
```

and when I try to uninstall that "-jango" package with simple `pip uninstall -jango` i get:

```
"no such option: -j"
```

How do I uninstall that package?!

Comment: Try with `pip uninstall -- -jango`; the `--` should terminate the possibility of further options.

Comment: Run `pip -V`, this will give you the directory where `pip` is installed (should end with `site-packages/pip`). Go to the parent dir (ends with `site-packages`), look for dirs (or `.egg` files) starting with `-jango` (e.g. `-jango.2.2.5.dist-info` etc). Rename the dir/file, this should fix `pip list`. If the metadata is not corrupted, this will also enable uninstalling, for that you need to check the list of files in either `Django-2.2.5.dist-info/RECORD` or `Django-2.2.5.egg/EGG-INFO/sources.txt` and replace all occurences of `-jango` with `Django`.

Comment: How are packages named?  Just by directory name?  If so, just rename the directory from `-jango` to `xjango`.  If the name appears in some text file - edit it.

Answer (score 0):

As with most unix-y utilities, you should be able to pass verbatim parameters after a double-dash (that'd separate switches from arguments):

```
pip uninstall -- -jango
```

Comment: not working. i get these messages:

ERROR: Invalid requirement: '-jango'

or if I dont space:

no such option: ---jango